# Python-Pandas -How to update multiple row values with a condition on unique column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, insert-update

I have a main dataframe for which few  row values are missing for a candidate. And i have an excel file for which few of these missing values are present in this excel file. So i am trying to update the  values from excel file to the main dataframe.

```
Main dataframe : df

Employee_id Previous_sal current_salary
1                    
1                 
1                   
2       1000          1500
```

The main dataframe will have multiple rows for each employee.

```
Second dataframe/excel = a.bkp_csv

Employee_id Previous_sal current_salary
1              2000       3000
```

Tried code:

```
test2=pd.read_csv('./a_bkp.csv')
emp.update(test2,join='left',overwrite=False)
```

But using the above its getting updated to the incorrect employee id's also .
I just want to update the employee who has **null values** from second file to first dataframe.

Expected : Output

```
Main dataframe: df
Employee_id Previous_sal current_salary
1            2000        3000                
1            2000        3000     
1            2000        3000
2            1000        1500
```

Answer (score 0):

two solutions for this:

- if you are willing to change the index of the table to 'Employee_id' and it won't mess up any other process in your code, then you can do:

```py
emp.set_index('Employee_id', inplace=True)
test2.set_index('Employee_id', inplace=True)
emp.fillna(test2)
```

- if you don't want to change the index, we can first create an intermediate table like the following:

```py
df = emp.merge(test2, on='Employee_id', how='left')
```

`df` will be a table like this:

|  | Employee_id | Previous_sal_x | current_salary_x | Previous_sal_y | current_salary_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | nan | nan | 2000 | 3000 |
| 1 | 1 | nan | nan | 2000 | 3000 |
| 2 | 1 | nan | nan | 2000 | 3000 |
| 3 | 2 | 1000 | 1500 | nan | nan |

then we fill the null values from `_x` columns from `_y` columns:

```
df['Previous_sal'] = df['Previous_sal_x'].fillna(df['Previous_sal_y'])
df['current_salary'] = df['current_salary_x'].fillna(df['current_salary_y'])
emp = df[['Employee_id', 'Previous_sal', 'current_salary']]
```

`emp` will be:

|  | Employee_id | Previous_sal | current_salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2000 | 3000 |
| 1 | 1 | 2000 | 3000 |
| 2 | 1 | 2000 | 3000 |
| 3 | 2 | 1000 | 1500 |

Comment: Thank You . I see after executing the datetime datatypes in my original dataframe has been changed to object datatype . Why so ? and can we have the original datatypes without any change? –

Comment: it is probably because of some null values. You can change them back to datetime by running a line like this: `df['time_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_col'])`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do what your question asks:

```py
emp = ( emp
    .reset_index()
    .set_index('Employee_id')
    .fillna(test2.set_index('Employee_id'))
    .reset_index()
    .set_index('index')
    .rename_axis(index=None) )
```

Output:

```
   Employee_id  Previous_sal  current_salary
0            1        2000.0          3000.0
1            1        2000.0          3000.0
2            1        2000.0          3000.0
3            2        1000.0          1500.0
```

Explanation:

- use `reset_index()` to save the original dataframe index in a column named `index`
- use `set_index()` on `emp` to make the `Employee_id` column the index
- use `set_index()` on `test2` to make the `Employee_id` column the index
- use `fillna()` to fill `NaN` values in `emp` using values in the `test2` row with matching `Employee_id`
- use `reset_index()` to restore `Employee_id` as a column
- use `set_index()` to restore the original index (which we stored in the `index` column)
- use `rename_axis()` to change the name of the index from `index` back to None.

Comment: Thank You . I see after executing the datetime datatypes in my original dataframe has been changed to object datatype . Why  so ? and  can we have the original datatypes without any change?

Comment: I'm not sure why the datetime datatypes in your dataframe changed to object datatype since those columns were not included in the sample input in your question, but it sounds like the sort of thing that can happen when values of Nan (or None or other forms of null) are introduced into a column of non-object datatype. If these datetime columns currently have no null values, please try using the DataFrame methods `infer_objects` or `convert_dtypes` on them.